# trouble getting JWT for a server to server application in C

Tags: google-drive-api

I have trouble getting a JWT for a server to server application.
With the following command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mypkcs12-private.p12 -out privateKey.pem.
```

Following the doc /docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount,
I encoded my header

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
```

and my claim

```
{"iss":"******@developer.gserviceaccount.com","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file,"aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","exp":1401710837,"iat":1401707237}
```

in base64. so I created the base64 encoded signature using (b64header.b64claim), my private key and HMAC function. When I request the token using curl, I get an invalid_grant error. I tried many things but I don't know where the issue is.

here is the code

```
static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{

  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  MemoryStruct *mem = (MemoryStruct *)userp;

  mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(mem->memory == NULL) {
    /* out of memory! */ 
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }

  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;


  return realsize;
}


char *base64encode(const char *normal, size_t length) 
{
    BIO *bmem, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *bptr;
    char *buff = NULL;
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
    BIO_write(b64, normal, (int) length);
    if (BIO_flush(b64) != 1) {
        return NULL;
    }

    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);

    buff = (char *) malloc(bptr->length);
    memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length-1);
    buff[bptr->length - 1] = 0;

    BIO_free_all(b64);
    b64 = NULL;
    return buff;
}

char * createClaimSet(char * address)
{
    char * output = NULL;
    char claim_format[] =  "{\"iss\":\"%s\",\"scope\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file\",\"aud\":\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token\",\"exp\":%ld,\"iat\":%ld}";
    size_t len_address = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    time_t iat;
    time_t exp;

    time(&iat);
    exp = iat + 3600;

    if (address) len_address = strlen(address);
    size = strlen(claim_format);
    output = (char*) calloc(len_address + size - 8 + 20 + 1, sizeof(char));
    sprintf(output,claim_format, address, exp, iat);
    printf(output);

    return output;
}


char *b64HmacSha256fct(char *line, char * keyp12, size_t size)
{
    char *Hmac64 = "";
    const EVP_MD *evp_md = EVP_sha256();
    unsigned char md[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int md_len;


    // HMAC
    HMAC(evp_md, keyp12, (int)size, (const unsigned char*) line, strlen(line), md, &md_len);

    Hmac64=base64encode(md, md_len);

    return Hmac64;
}

int AuthServiceAccount(CURL *curl)
{
    char * b64_claim_set = NULL;
    char * claim_set = NULL;
    char * header64 = NULL;
    char * JWT = NULL;
    char * toSign = NULL;
    char * sig64 = NULL;
    char * str = NULL;
    char * data = NULL;
    char * privateKey = NULL;
    char grant[] = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer";
    char uri[] = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    char header[] = "{\"alg\":\"RS256\",\"typ\":\"JWT\"}";
    char emailAddress[] = "xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    char PKCS12_FILE_PATH[] = "C:\\temp\\mykey.key";
    FILE * pInputP12Name = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    MemoryStruct writeMemory;
    size_t fileP12size = 0;
    size_t lclaim64 = 0;
    size_t lclaimSet = 0;
    size_t lheader64 = 0;
    size_t lstr = 0;
    size_t resultat;

    header64 = base64encode(header, strlen(header));
    if (header64) lheader64 = strlen(header64);

    claim_set = createClaimSet(emailAddress);
    if (claim_set) lclaimSet = strlen(claim_set);
    b64_claim_set = base64encode(claim_set, lclaimSet);
    if (b64_claim_set) lclaim64 = strlen(b64_claim_set);
    str = (char*) calloc(lclaim64+1, sizeof(char));
    if (!str) return 1;
    for (i=0; i<lclaim64; i++) {
        if (isprint(b64_claim_set[i])) {
            str[j] = b64_claim_set[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';

    if (str) lstr = strlen(str);
    toSign = (char*) calloc(lheader64 + 1 + lstr + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (!toSign) return 1;
    sprintf(toSign,"%s.%s",header64,str);

    pInputP12Name = fopen (PKCS12_FILE_PATH,"rb");
    if (pInputP12Name==NULL) {
        perror ("Error opening file");
        return (-1);
    }
    else
    {
        resultat = _fseeki64(pInputP12Name, 0, SEEK_END);
        fileP12size= (size_t) ftell(pInputP12Name);
        rewind(pInputP12Name);
        privateKey = (char *) calloc(fileP12size+1, sizeof(char));
        resultat = fread (privateKey,sizeof(char),fileP12size,pInputP12Name);
        fclose (pInputP12Name);
    }

    sig64 = b64HmacSha256fct(toSign,privateKey,fileP12size);
    if (!sig64) return 1;

    JWT = (char *) calloc(strlen(toSign) + 1 + strlen(sig64) + 1, sizeof(char));
    sprintf(JWT,"%s.%s", toSign, sig64); 

    if (curl) {
        FILE* pfile = NULL;
        size_t size = 0;

        memset(&writeMemory,'\0',sizeof(MemoryStruct));

        size = strlen(grant)+strlen("&assertion=")+strlen(JWT);
        data = (char *) calloc(size+1, sizeof(char));
        if (!data) return 1;
        sprintf(data,"%s&assertion=%s", grant, JWT);

        curl_easy_reset(curl);
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, uri );
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443 );
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(data));
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &writeMemory);
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        printf("%s",writeMemory.memory);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    curl_version_info_data *CurlVers;

    CurlVers = curl_version_info( CURLVERSION_NOW );
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    AuthServiceAccount(curl);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();

exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation states](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt) that you must use [base64url encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7), which is a variant of base64 encoded that uses URL-safe characters.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your answer, I tried the base64url encoding but the result is always the same. I think that the issue is due to the signature but i don't find the solution.

Comment: The problem was also the signature. First, I remove the "=" in the string "toSign", Then I use SHA256 and after the base64url encode.